# Fieldtype runs validate() multiple times?

Tags: add-on-development, fieldtype

I'm trying to create a custom fieldtype that's `display_field()` function produces a collection of `<input>` boxes. The problem I am having is that the `validate()` function in my ft.x_fieldtype.php file is getting run each time for each `<input>` it seems.

Can anyone see a way around this?

Comment: What are your input names for all of your input boxes?

Comment: That was my first question too. For multiple input boxes there should be an array of fields all sharing the same name.

Comment: I have `<?= $field->field_name ?>[credit_card][expiration_month] ?> and <?= $field->field_name ?>[credit_card][expiration_year] ?>` for example for each of the name="" parameters.

Comment: It might be due to the nested array you have. Maybe try  `<?= $field->field_name ?>[credit_card_expiration_month] ?>`?

Comment: That didn't seem to help. Can you think of an example fieldtype that does multiple fields but only requires one validation call? I was looking at matrix but since it validates each column what I am seeing is an expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I came up with is to set an instance variable such as `$has_already_validated` to prevent further validation. It seems to work as there is only one instance created at least. Here's an example:

```
class My_fieldtype_ft extends EE_Fieldtype {
    private $has_already_validated = FALSE;

    function validate($data) 
    {
         if ($this->has_already_validated) return TRUE;
         $this->has_already_validated = TRUE;

         // your validation code
    }
}
```